# How can I create a branch out of local unpushed commits?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have 2 unpushed commits in my master branch. E.g.

```
A<-B<-C
```

and remote is on C and local HEAD is in A.
What I would like to to put the A and B in a branch instead of pushing to master.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Make a new branch (say, `b1`), push to remote. Then reset local `master` with the remote master.

```
$ git checkout -b b1              # create and checkout new branch 'b1'
$ git push origin b1              # push to remote 'b1' 

$ git checkout master             # checkout to master branch
$ git reset --hard origin/master  # reset local master with remote master
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new branch (`git branch new_branch`) and push that one to remote.

If you want to move your commits (eg rebase master):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

New branch:

```
git branch new_branch
```

Reset in branch master:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```